# How do I set default location and Zoom level for google map api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When my map shows, it always start at a fixed location (near Africa).

Then, I use the following code to center the map to the location I want.

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 14.0f));
```

My question is that could I set a default location and zoom level before the map shows?

Because I don't want my users to see the animation at the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: This qustion helped.... Even if location is not enabled ...animateCamera points to somewhere in africa ... wiered ! ...`moveCamera` is the best solution for this

Comment: hahahhaha.......+1 for this question, you asked my heart out . :D..."it always start at a fixed location (near Africa)"........rofll.....thanks even though.

Comment: @akash89 It starts from LatLng(0.0,0.0) as expected: https://www.google.com/maps/@0,0,5z I'm not sure what makes you roll on the floor laughing literally (if I'm not mistaken), but I'm happy that you are happy :)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

you can use this to zoom directly without the animation :

```
map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );
```

Comment: i have minimum latitude/longitude and maximum latitude/longitude then how to set???

Comment: you can add new question for that so i can post the full answer for you, but in short you will have to use LatLngBounds.Builder to build bounds and use that.

Comment: @Saksak My problem is that I am waiting on the GPS to grab `MyLocation` so that I can move and zoom the map to the user's location.  Since the map is initialized in the XML, I can't figure out how to keep the jump from happening.  Ideally, I would hide the map until `MyLocation` is found then show it.

Comment: when i placed map it gave me an error and told me to create a variable 'map'. is it possible to import or something?

Comment: @huicheese map is the name of your instance of GoogleMap, replace it with the name you have.

Comment: One can also replace `moveCamera` with `animateCamera` for a smooth zoom

Comment: animate camera is nice, but if your map is just initialised, it smooth-zooms very slowly from fully zoomed out, try a mixture

Answer (score 93):

Take a look at the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#configure_initial_state

The way to do it is slightly different depending on whether you are adding the map via XML or programmatically.  If you are using XML, you can do it as follows:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  map:cameraBearing="112.5"
  map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
  map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
  map:cameraTilt="30"
  map:cameraZoom="13"/>
```

If you are doing it programmatically, you can do the following:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(-33, 150))
    .zoom(13)
    .build();
MapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions()
    .camera(camera));
```

Comment: Good answer. Actually, this one is more suitable for this question.

Comment: in xml i get lint error `Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment`

Comment: If even with xmlns:map="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" you still have the same error. Try to add this xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" and use "tools:" instead of "map:"

Comment: Link to documentation with all the options: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#using_xml_attributes

Comment: was looking for layout attributes, work perfectly . thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you want to load `Google Map` at any initial `Location` programmatically then you can use this piece of code,

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // getChildFragmentManager inside fragments.
CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(initialLatLng) // your initial co-ordinates here. like, LatLng initialLatLng
                    .zoom(zoom_level)
                    .build();
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().camera(cp));
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rl_map, mapFragment).commit();
```

Add this piece of code for `layout`

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rl_map"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

This will load `GoogleMap` at particular `Location` directly i.e, initialLatLng.

Answer (score 3):

I created a handle to `SupportMapFragment` and set its `visibility` to `View.INVISIBLE` using `SupportMapFragment.getView().setVisibility()`.  Then, in the `onLocationChanged` callback that my class implements, I check if `INVISIBLE` and set to `VISIBLE` if true.  This gets rid of the jumping you see on load while allowing you to dynamically initialize the starting position.  In my case I am centering the camera around the user's location, so `onLocationChanged` is called immediately because of `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.

Your requirements may be different, but either way you just need to set the visibility to `INVISIBLE` and then find a good place to set `VISIBLE` after your appropriate data has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

you can use directy CameraUpdate using static latlong

```
 LatLong latlong = new LatLong(lat, long);
 CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 15);
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);
```