# Google map start showing my current location from africa and then moves camera to my current location

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I know this question have been asked before but, I didn't got the solution. My android application starts showing my location as in Africa and then camera moves towards my current location. Can anyone help to understand this behaviour and provide me some solution to fix this.

below is part of my code

```
    //ON CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL USING GOOGLECLIENTAPI
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    checkPermission();
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        pointUserCurrentLocationOnMap(location);
        userLocation = location;

        saveLocationIfDoesNotExistInSqliteAndBackend();
    } else {
        checkSettingIsProper();
    }
}

     public void pointUserCurrentLocationOnMap(Location lastknownLocation) {

    mMap.clear();
    enableUserLocationButton(true);
    userLocation = lastknownLocation;

    currentLocation = new LatLng(lastknownLocation.getLatitude(), lastknownLocation.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("You");
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_person_pin_circle_black_24dp));
    marker.showInfoWindow();

//bounds= latlngbound which is initialize when user search some thing
    if (bounds != null) {     
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, (int) JobSmithApplication.convertPixelsToDp(50f, this)));
    } else {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 14f));
    }

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);

}
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

When the map loads for the first time, it opens lat-long 0,0 which is the centre point of our equator, then when "onChange" is triggered, it will load the new lat-long location and gets updated. So the camera moves to the user's current location. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide some doc link so i can read it in more deeply

Comment: Try this....https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/

Comment: Link you provided does not say anything about default coordinate 0.0 which is in africa. However i found the solution. I was using animateCamera() which was causing issue. Solution was to use moveCamera() as he says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530315/is-it-possible-in-android-google-maps-to-change-default-location-from-south-afri/21530461#21530461)

Comment: can you please try this page too https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-maps-to-an-android-app-with-google-play-services/

Answer (score 0):

check your lastKnownLocation's latitude and longitude in logcat and see what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Set your application specific location in your configuration or globally. When you are initializing your google map animate your view to your specified location.

```
GoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Configuration.DEFAULT_LAT, Configuration.DEFAULT_LONG), 14.0f));
```

Whenever you will open your app above code will change your application's map view to your configured location and when your location changes do the rest.