# Open map through intent with source and destination

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(intent);
```

Sorry for my english.

This code is working fine, however, its opening multiple routes. If I click on routes its going on map.

My question  is there any way by which I directly jump to map without user interaction.

Comment: Is it the default location you are looking for? That's already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157536/how-do-i-set-default-location-and-zoom-level-for-google-map-api-v2

Comment: I think there is no way to change having multiple routes.