# I need to get part of a map region in android

Tags: android

I need to create a map application for a certain region, so I wanted to know how do I just leave this region on the map in android, I want to get only this region without the rest of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the coordinates of your region using the Google Map API in Android. See this link [How do I set default location and Zoom level for google map api v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157536/how-do-i-set-default-location-and-zoom-level-for-google-map-api-v2)

Comment: Thank you for your help.